# Protect OSB flooring from moisture

Tags: flooring, deck, shed

I built a 13x8 floor on concrete piers. The idea is to have an 8x8 sauna and an 5x8 deck.

I knew I would have to trim siding of the outside front of the sauna to accommodate the 2x8 beams that are still extending out for the deck.  But now I am worried about the floor board absorbing moisture from the beam. I last minute decided not to use a vapour barrier over the insulated floor. Are there any suggestions or should I rip out the floor boards, use a vapour barrier, and install new floor boards?

[image]

Comment: Normally this site isn't for product recommendations but I suggest you pull up the OSB and lay down a specifically moisture-resistant product like AdvanTech. The manufacturer also has great documentation on how to use it for flooring where vapor is a significant concern. (I have no affiliation with the company or products) https://www.huberwood.com/blog/avoiding-the-moisture-sandwich

Comment: I looked up the current flooring, it is LP Top Notch 350, tech specs talk about moisture resistance, and it costs more than marine grade plywood. Would you be comfortable with either that wood or this wood resting on that pressure treated beam, absorbing a bit of rain water through the PT 2x8. I could put some membrane around it..

Answer (score 1):

I'd bite the bullet, pull up the OSB, and use marine-grade plywood, if you have any suspicion at all that it may get wet for a prolonged period.

Your question is also a bit confusing about a vapour barrier. I would put a vapour barrier *under* the deck, to keep moisture from coming up out of the ground and condensing on the cool, insulated deck.

If you are absolutely certain that the deck will not get wet from above, then a vapour barrier might be all you'll need, but I think it is essential either way.

Depending on the weight of the platform, you should be able to jack it up and lay down your vapour barrier without replacing the decking. You'll have to re-level, of course, but if you have piers with screw-adjustments, you'll be laughing. :-)

Comment: There is vapour barrier under the rocks. But I have a false floor (PT plywood), fiberglass insulation, and then the subfloor. I was thinking of adding a sheet of poly under the subfloor nut did not. I looked up my subfloor LP TopNotch 350 and it has "superior moisture resistance" . What do you think? Thanks

Comment: Well, since this is a sauna, I guess the risk of water coming *down* is minimal, and as you note, you have a vapour barrier below the gravel. Feeling lucky? At first, I was thinking your use above was something wetter than a sauna.